# Not Showing Detailsview in ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, asp.net-ajax

i used ModalPopupExtender today only ,so i have not much idea how it works

i am stuck in problem here

i have Gridview showing all students data,now when i click on Linkbutton of particular student in Gridview than that student data should shown in Detailsview on popup

i am getting a perticular student data in Detailsview but its not showing in popup,should i have to add anything else here?

here is my code for modelpopupextender

aspx code-

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="Stu_id" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Stu_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Stu_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullname" HeaderText="name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnviewdetails" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                                CommandName="Select" Text="select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Stu_id") %>' 
                                onclick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                 </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="btnshowpopup" runat="server"/>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlpopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnshowpopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="btncancel" BackgroundCssClass="pop">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" Width="500px" style="display:none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>



                <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Stu_id" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                        <Fields>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Stu_id" HeaderText="ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullname" HeaderText="Fullname" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                        </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
                  <div id="div1" style="display:none">                     
                       <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
                 </div> 
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>             
    </asp:Panel>
```

cs code-

```
public partial class Admin_Default : System.Web.UI.Page


 {
    portalDal dal = new portalDal();
    adminBal bal = new adminBal();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = bal.student_bind();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.DetailsView1.Visible = true;
    LinkButton l1 = (LinkButton)sender;
    dal.stu_id = Convert.ToInt16(l1.CommandArgument);
    DetailsView1.DataSource = bal.select_student(dal);
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
    this.UpdatePanel2.Update();
    this.mdlpopup.Show();

}
```

bal file-

```
public DataTable student_bind()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Stu_registration", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable aselect_student(portalDal dal)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select_student", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stu_id", dal.stu_id);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I few observations:

- You need to move the ModalPopupExtender control outside the Panel that you are using for the modal popup (pnlpopup, in your case).
- Once you do that, you'llneed to change your CancelControlID to `UpdatePanel2$btncancel` (otherwise your ModalPopupExtender won't be able to find the "btncancel" control inside that UpdatePanel).
- You also need to move the control you're using as the "TargetControlID" (btnshowpopup, in your case) outside of the modal popup control.

So your markup should look like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" Width="500px" style="display:none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                DataKeyNames="Stu_id" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Stu_id" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullname" HeaderText="Fullname" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
            <div id="div1" style="display:none">                     
                <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
            </div> 
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>             
</asp:Panel>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlpopup" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="btnshowpopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" 
    CancelControlID="UpdatePanel2$btncancel" BackgroundCssClass="pop">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Button ID="btnshowpopup" runat="server"/>
```

I would also change the order of the "Update" and "Show" commands in your codebaheind file.  I don't think it will make any difference, but it is definitely more logical:

```
this.mdlpopup.Show();
this.UpdatePanel2.Update();
```

Comment: thanks for replying my question but same problem , even popup is not showing up when i click gridview linkbutton,only shows up when clicks on btnshowpopup

Comment: Oh no!  Sorry, @vikas.  Are you getting any error messages?  For instance, JavaScript errors?  Also, it's a longshot, but you should trying defining the GridView in the first UpdatePanel as a trigger for the UpdatePanel that contains the DetailsView.

Comment: thanks @jadarnel but i just solved it this morning,actually i fired trigger in updatepanel2 as control id of gridview and wrote all GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged code in LinkButton1_Click,and did as u said moved modelpopup outside panel and added some tags and it worked,and thanks again for giving solution

Comment: You're very welcome, @vikas!  I'm glad I could help.  Feel free to post an answer explaining your final solution, or you can mark my answer as the "Accepted answer" - or both!  Or neither =)  No pressure.